# PGFPlot: Single plot even too big for main memory

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tex-core, memory

If we run the following python program, we get a 100.000 lines `test.dat`

```
import random
with open("test.dat","w") as f:
   f.write("x y label\n")
   for i in range(0,100000):
     clazz = 0
     if i % 2 == 0:
         clazz = 1
     f.write(str(random.uniform(-10,10))+" "+str(random.uniform(-10,10))+" "+str(clazz)+"\n")
```

If I now run `pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex` on the following MWE it crashes with:

This fails with: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].`

However `kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf` is reporting:

```
/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

However in the first file this setting is not there. In the other 2 I can scale this to 12000000 followed by `fmtutil-sys --all` but then:

- I still have this error;
- It still tells me I have 5000000. However it seems to pick up the values, because if I overshoot (15000000) I get the error `Ouch---my internal constants have been clobbered!---case 14` but why is it reporting 5, if I changed the setting to 12?

How is this possible?

How to get this working? (PS: yes with 100K you will have some overlap, however in reality it is near 50K, and I want to avoid preprocessing to reduce overlap, because overlap also depends on scaling).

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}
\centering
\resizebox {\columnwidth} {!} {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
    \begin{axis}[legend style={
at={(0,0)},legend columns=2,  /tikz/column 2/.style={
                column sep=10pt,
            },
anchor=north west,at={(axis description cs:0,-0.03)}}]]
    \addplot[fill opacity=0.4,draw opacity=0.4,
            scatter/classes={
                0={mark=*,green},
                1={mark=*,red}
                },
                scatter, only marks,
                scatter src=explicit symbolic]
         table[x=x,y=y,meta=label]
            {test.dat};
            \legend{Class A, Class B}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

there are limits to how big you can make the settings, however you could use luatex which uses dynamic memory. It takes ages (and ages to render in xpdf) but

[image]

you were missing two `%` at ends of lines which I also added

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}


\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}
\centering
\resizebox {\columnwidth} {!} {%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
    \begin{axis}[legend style={
at={(0,0)},legend columns=2,  /tikz/column 2/.style={
                column sep=10pt,
            },
anchor=north west,at={(axis description cs:0,-0.03)}}]]
    \addplot[fill opacity=0.4,draw opacity=0.4,
            scatter/classes={
                0={mark=*,green},
                1={mark=*,red}
                },
                scatter, only marks,
                scatter src=explicit symbolic]
         table[x=x,y=y,meta=label]
            {test.dat};
            \legend{Class A, Class B}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%%%%
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but why do I need to add %%%%? This is simply comment, isn't it?

Comment: @robert you don't need `%%%%` but you _do_ need `%` otherwise your box has a word-space at start and end so the image is scaled smaller than need be compare `\fbox{x}` with `fbox{ x }`